# Where does niceness stop?

Tags: discussion

Are the following phrases considered nice on this site?

> Dont be egositic
>
> But continue to think that you're special.
>
> your latest edit is rather childish

Comment: The most effective way to deal with a comment that violates the "be nice" policy is to **flag it**, as per my answer below. Keeping a running list of the not-nice comments on meta is not the right way to handle it. Responding with your own comment telling the user they are not being nice is also not the right way to handle it. Please just flag and then go on with your day.

Comment: @ff524 Now I do have the right to flag.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a link to the question where these phrases appear.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Please complain to ff524 about that; she removed those links.

Comment: Notifying @ff524 .

Comment: @Federico Those phrases were in comments, which have been deleted,  so the links were removed.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni But the link to the originator of such comments is seen in the edit history.

Comment: It's also worth noting that these comments were made in response to other comments that were also deleted. OP's question got 10 downvotes for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

No, see the [be nice](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy.

The appropriate response is to flag the comment, then move on.

I would note that a comment like "if you had ever applied for a job like this you would know that" is also not very nice.

Comment: Thank you, got it. I should have said "you **might probably** know that" instead. Reading just a two-page cover letter and double-checking takes more than 5 minutes...

Comment: @Hexal A nicer thing to say might be "How long does it take you to check an application before submitting? I find that reading and checking even just a cover letter takes more than five minutes." Rather than making assumptions about anyone else's experiences (really, everyone is different!)